# P5.JS Animated GIF doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gif, p5.js

How can i load in an animated gif that works on all modern browsers with p5.js?

```
img1 = loadImage('2.gif');
image(img1, 15, y, 20, 40);
```

This only shows the first frame of the GIF.

Comment: Useful sketch: https://editor.p5js.org/kjhollen/sketches/S1bVzeF8Z

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this.

**1. Use `createImg` instead of `loadImage`**

Change your code to:

```
img1 = createImg('2.gif');
img1.position(20, 40);
```

**2. Use a Dependency**

You need to add this to your project: https://github.com/antiboredom/p5.gif.js/tree/master

Your code should look like this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600,600);
  gif = loadGif('2.gif');
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  image(gif, 20, 40);
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Code And what about the `createImg()` function? And can you please be more specific than just saying it doesn't work? What happens exactly?