# knowing if the file uploaded by user was loaded in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

How do I know whether the user's uploaded file is completly being loaded or it's being loading.

I want to show "you have succeeded in uploading" after the loading is finished so I got to know if the file is uploaded completely...

BTW file can be loaded by user creating this code.
input = createFileInput(handleFile);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the file from the `<input>` with a function like `loadImage()`, the all of the `loadXXX` functions in p5.js take success and failure callback function parameters that executes when the image is finished loading.

```js
let input;
let img;

function setup() {
  input = createFileInput(handleFile);
  input.position(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (img) {
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

function handleFile(file) {
  print(`File selected: ${file.name}`);
  img = loadImage(
    file.data,
    () => print('Image Loaded Successfully.'),
    () => print('Image Failed to Load.'),
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

For the record when using a file input element like this nothing is actually being "uploaded" just loaded into the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Reply!!!
It really worked!!

By the way, how can I display loading gif image while the mp3 is uploading?

Comment: As I said. Nothing is being "uploaded" but if you want to display something while the sound file is being parsed/processed you should be able to set a flag when the `handleFile` function is called, when that flag is set display whatever loading graphics you want in the draw() function, and then unset the flag when one of the `loadImage` callback functions is invoked. However because the main thread of the browser may be busy processing the file I'm not sure how many times draw() will actually get called.

Comment: As far as displaying gif files specifically see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650025/p5-js-animated-gif-doesnt-work